# Display product total by tax

Tags: magento-1.9, tax-class

I need to display the total price of products by tax in orders and invoices on magento 1.9.
So:

Product001 // 100€ exc. tax // tax 6% // Total tax: 6€ // Total 106€
Product002 // 100€ exc. tax // tax 21% // Total tax: 21€ // Total 121€
Product003 // 200€ exc. tax // tax 6% // Total tax: 12€ // Total 212€
Product004 // 200€ exc. tax // tax 21% // // Total tax: 42€ // Total 242€

What i need is to get the total by tax:
**Tax 6% = 300€ (Product001 + Product003)** // Total tax: 18€ // total: 318€
**Tax 21% = 300€ (Product002 + Product004)**...

How to get the sum of all product prices, exclude tax, of certain tax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every product has multiple price columns. This depends on what collection you are returning.

if it is order_item it will be:

**price** = excl tax

**original_price** = incl tax

and on invoice_item it would be:

**price** = excl tax

**price_incl_tax** = incl tax

To return the values do the following:
`$product->getPrice()` or `$product->getOriginalPrice()` or `$product->priceInclTax()`

i hope this helps by making the calculations you need.

Comment: Thank you so much Myron! With that i only get the product price right? I have to get the sum of all products with the same tax.

Comment: Yes indeed, you could save the price in a variable and make calculations using those variables.